# Conversion of float* to char*, int* and char* does not produce expected results

Tags: c, pointers, casting

As far as I know the output should be like 3.14,3.14,3.14 and 256,256,256 right? But this produces a different output. Can anyone please guide me through this and tell me why this happens?

```
    main()
    {
     float a = 3.14;
     int b = 256;
     char *p, *p1;
     p = (char *) &a;
     p1 = (char *) &b;
     printf("\nFLOAT:");
     printf("\nValue of *p=%f",*p);
     printf("\nValue of a=%f",a);
     printf("\nValue of *p=%f",*p);
     printf("\n\nINTEGER:");
     printf("\nValue of *p1=%d",*p1);
     printf("\nValue of b=%d",b);
     printf("\nValue of *p1=%d",*p1);
    }

    Output:
    FLOAT:
    Value of *p=0.000000
    Value of a=3.140000
    Value of *p=3.140001

    INTEGER:
    Value of *p1=0
    Value of b=256
    Value of *p1=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got slightly different answers that you did (http://ideone.com/RG4uq) which is not really suprising given that the behavior of variadic functions with mixed floating point and integral types is undefined.

Here's what is happening.  Assuming memory starts at address 0x50000000, 32-bit machine, little endian

```
50000000  c3  f5  48  40   (a)
50000004  00  01  00  00   (b)
50000008  00  00  00  50   (p)
5000000c  04  00  00  50   (p1)
```

Type of a is float, type of b is int, type of p is char*, type of p1 is char*.

For integers, you see

- print p1 as an int  ==>  `*p1` is the byte at address 50000004, which is 0, so 0 is printed.
- print b as an int ==> well obviously `b` is 256 because it is an int.
- print p1 as an int  ==>  `*p1` is the byte at address 50000004, which is 0, so 0 is printed (as before).

On a little endian machine, you can even try printing `p1[1]` as an integer and you will see 1 (interesting, eh?  See http://ideone.com/daS6d).

For floats, things are different.  On many processors, say the x86-64, parameters are passed in registers.  You are calling `printf` three times.  Each time the thing that will be printed comes from `xmm0` (assuming the x86-64).  But notice when you first try to print `*p` which is a char, *nothing* is passed in `xmm0` (`*p` is passed in `%edi`) so whatever junk you had in there gets printed (could be 0, or 0.0234892374 or whatever).  But next you pass a *real* float in `xmm0` and print 3.14.  But when you come around for the third printf, again you don't pass anything (because `*p` is a char) and so what is left in `xmm0`?  That's right 3.14.  It could have been something else, perhaps, but most likely it hasn't changed. :)

Answer (score 5):

The expression `*p` has type `char`. The format specifier `%f` requires an argument of type `float`. Passing an argument of the wrong type to a variadic function like `printf` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 for this answer plus the corrections in the comments to dasblinkenlight's answer. :)

Comment: These are the outputs I get when I use %c instead of %f for printing the p and p1 bro:http://codepad.org/fTvUrW83(Symbol Output) http://ideone.com/KNdsr(Blank Output).

Comment: @glnarayanan In your question you weren't really clear about why you found your output surprising. I assumed it was because the line `printf("\nValue of *p=%f",*p);` produced different outputs the two times you executed it. In your new program this is no longer the case, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @glnarayanan Oh I see that you edited the question to be more specific since I've first read it. No, the output you expected would not be the correct result. There are no circumstances under which dereferencing a char pointer would ever give you a floating point value. For one thing a char is only a single byte and floating point values consist of multiple bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not behaving as expected because float* and char* are of different sizes. Converting them may sacrifice your expression accuracy!

Comment: It is unlikely that float* and char* are different sizes although float and char almost certainly are.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you are invoking undefined behavior when you pass a `char` type to `printf` using a format specifier of `%f` and as such you should't *expect* anything in particular.

The long answer is implementation dependent but what follows is my observation of what is likely occurring on your platform.  When you ask `printf` to print a `double` value (as with the `%f` format specifier), it reads the next `sizeof(double)` bytes from the stack and interprets it as a floating point value and prints it.  In the first `printf` call, the first time a new stack frame is generated, the data on the stack after the bits that form the `char` you actually passed equate to a zero floating point value.  In the second call to `printf`, a new stack frame is generated, probably overwriting the same space that the first call did.  In this case, a full `double` value is present and it is printed as expected.  The stack frame is "destroyed" when the function returns.  As a matter of efficiency, the stack frame is not typically zeroed out when a function returns and the contents remain.  In your third call to `printf`, you again pass a single byte whereas you ask `printf` to interpret `sizeof(double)` bytes as a floating point value.  The stack frame from the previous call to `printf` now contains the value of the `double` passed from the prior call, with one of those bytes overwritten with the byte from the new argument which results in the value printed.

If I change your second `printf` call to:

```
printf("\nValue of a=%f", 1.234);
```

the third call to `printf` prints (on my system):

```
Value of *p=1.234000
```

which seems to validate the logic presented above.

In summary, you are asking `printf` to read more data from the stack than you actually passed to the function and as such you the results are undefined.  In your case, the data read is remnants of previous calls which explains the result you get on your specific platform.  (As Ray points out, the actual way the argument is passed could vary as this is implementation dependent.  Some systems will pass the value in a register but the point remains the same.)

Comment: Passing a `char` using `%d` is perfectly fine. `char` gets promoted to `int` anyway. It's just `%f` that's the problem.

Comment: @sepp2k, I think it depends actually.  If `char` is unsigned and `char` and `int` are the same size then the argument actually gets promoted to `unsigned int` which makes the call undefined.